# Cesium fragment shader error for displaying billoards

Tags: crash, webgl, cesiumjs

I'm using billoards for my entities.  On MacOS, they are properly displayed, but on Linux, the webgl crashes.  Sometimes it is enough to just kill the browser, sometime I have to kill X completely.

Sample code:

```
const entityOptions = {
    id: id,
    position: position,
    billboard: {
        image: '/assets/symbols/symbol.svg'
    }
};
this.viewer.entities.add(new Cesium.Entity(entityOptions));
```

I do get the following stack trace:

```
f         @Cesium.js:formatted:45195
y         @Cesium.js:formatted:45312
d._bind   @Cesium.js:formatted:45369
G         @Cesium.js:formatted:78362
k.draw    @Cesium.js:formatted:78607
n.execute @Cesium.js:formatted:43787
Ge        @Cesium.js:formatted:106273
Xe        @Cesium.js:formatted:106363
tt        @Cesium.js:formatted:106661
$e        @Cesium.js:formatted:106575
ht        @Cesium.js:formatted:106889
pt        @Cesium.js:formatted:106900
xe.render @Cesium.js:formatted:107294
A.render  @Cesium.js:formatted:115880
t         @Cesium.js:formatted:115580
```

Any hints?

Cesium version: 1.48.0

Edit:  The error was introduced in Cesium 1.45.  Version 1.44 works properly, 1.45 crashes.

Comment: What are the values of `id` and `position`?  Can you share the contents of `symbol.svg`?

Comment: Also, you should develop with an un-minified copy of Cesium, so you can see real function names in the stack trace.  Can you post a new stack trace with the correct names?